# How to install rubber paver around edges of synthetic grass area?

Tags: landscaping, pavers, backyard

I have a 15x20 synthetic grass area and I want to put something "soft" around the edges for the kid. My plan is to use rubber paver:

[image]

Like the 16x16 from Lowe's:

http://www.lowes.com/pd/Rubberific-Brown-Square-Rubber-Paver-Common-16-in-x-16-in-Actual-16-in-x-16-in/3715056

The questions I have are:

1. How to secure / bolt each of the paver down so they don't move? They are quite light and people kicking around will push them. Plus, one edge is the synthetic grass which is very soft by itself.
2. Should I put the rubber paver on the crushed rocks minus (1/2" or 5/8" as same as what underneath synthetic grass)? Or this kind of rubber paver should be on top of hard surface like concrete or another paver (either concrete or stone)?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I just installed the synthetic grasses and they look like this

[image]

It is very low to the rocks. Here is the top down. I nail the edges of the grasses by 10" nails so they won't move.

[image]

Comment: What is existing that your installing on top of? Dirt? Pavement? Gravel?   Lowe's online display never shows it but their in store displays usually have everything grouped and pamphlets or displays with pictures.

Comment: I have 5/8" minus compacted for 6 inches below. But even that, laying this 16x16 on top is something I am uncertain that it won't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that they are not very thick (one inch), but perhaps they are still heavy enough (5.4 lbs each). If you dig the dirt out, so that the top of the paver is level with the soil, then the paver should be held in place by the edge of the soil. Sand between them will help keep them from moving. There are also paver edge retstraints that you can buy/use:

[image]

Comment: I definitely use the edger like those. But how to I restrain the paver from the synthetic grass side? I could install the edger too but then it will show up as a visible line next to the grass.

Comment: @HP. I assume you can't hide the edge under the grass? If the pavers are level with the synth grass (accomplished by digging), you probably don't need an edger. Other ideas: perhaps you could turn the edger around so that the "teeth" (for lack of a better term) are under the pavers. Maybe if you set the pavers upright you could use glue or short (3/8") screws to fasten the edger to the pavers. Or maybe you could trim the edger with sheet metal screws so that it's short enough to  hide under the grass.

Comment: I updated with more photos. But I think it's possible to turn the edger teeth around like you said and glue them down. Nice idea.

Comment: @HP. Why can't you just dig out the soil so that the top of the paver is level with the astroturf?